# Hive install fails on Apache Ambari HDP 2.5

Tags: hive, ambari, hdpi

```js
    2017-07-27 09:49:35,736 - Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive2_2_5_3_0_37' returned 1. Error: Package: hive2_2_5_3_0_37-2.1.0.2.5.3.0-37.el6.noarch (HDP-2.5)
           Requires: python-argparse
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
2017-07-27 09:49:35,737 - Failed to install package hive2_2_5_3_0_37. Executing '/usr/bin/yum clean metadata'
2017-07-27 09:49:35,961 - Retrying to install package hive2_2_5_3_0_37 after 30 seconds
```

The argparse API works on system Python 2.6.6, but still install fails and prints 'Requires: python-argparse' log.
Can you please tell me what can I do?

Comment: what does "rpm -qa | grep python-argparse " returns ?

Comment: yes  IT returns nothing , i setup a fit python-argparse rpm(python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm) and solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error reported `Requires: python-argparse` indicates that python-argparse rpm is not installed. Install it using following command to resolve issue.

```
yum install python-argparse
```